# Adding EditText to title bar

Tags: android, android-edittext

Is it possible to add the EditText-Element to a selfmade title bar?

I've already tried making a Search-Dialog and succeeded but the Search Dialog appears from above, overlapps and disappears.

I have a Tabhost and the first Tab calls an activity that needs a Searchbar.
You just have to see the Searchbar in the first Tab.

I'm still learning in app development and thought that something like a searchbar wouldn't be that troublesome(i have already knowledge in PHP, Java and a little bit of Python).

I am thankfull for any kind of useful advice.

Comment: Is this a title bar or is this an actionbar?

Comment: yeah sorry after retrying i found out the actionbar would be better